# Question about the design of dynamic subclass hierarchy handling

Tags: generics, oop

I always tend to run into the following design problem that I'm never quite sure how to best resolve.  It usually starts with a hierarchy of Animals at my Circus:

```
Animal
  Cat
    BigCat
  Dog          
  Elephant
  ...
```

Now, each Animal needs to be trained, so that there is a separate method for each:

```
public interface Trainer {
    void train( BigCat animal );
    void train( Dog animal );
    void train( Elephant animal );
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that the CircusDirector doesn't give a damn.  He just throws Animals to the Trainer without even looking.

```
public class CircusDirector {
    public void work() {
        Trainer trainer = getTrainer();
        Animal animal = getAnimal();

        // ...and he doesn't know a frog from a pony,
        // so he tries to just:
        trainer.train(animal);
    }
}
```

Now, the Trainer can get an additional method like

```
void train( Animal animal );
```

where he'll use `instanceof` to send the animal to the appropriate method, but this seems ugly and doesn't come recommended.  Is there a better solution using generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've essentially implemented half of the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  You can have each of your Animal's provide an `acceptTrainer(Trainer t)` method which then call `t.train(this);`

Your Director would then call `animal.acceptTrainer(trainer);`

Also, I think generics info gets compiled out, so you can't do any fancy stuff relying on them.  It's best to get familiar with some of the patterns.

Comment: Does this mean that each subclass has to keep re-implementing the acceptTrainer() method?

Comment: @Jake: Sadly, yes, but as boilerplate goes, it's fairly minimal.

Comment: @Jake:  The animal-specific methods cannot be part of the Trainer -- that breaks basic encapsulation.  The Animal-specific training methods must be part of the Animal, not the Trainer.  So each Animal must provide Training-specific methods.  acceptTrainer is one way to shape the API between Director, Trainer and each Animal instance.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing looks like it could be solved quite neatly with [the Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or, a little more precisely, double-dispatch.

Have your animals implement a Trainable interface:

```
interface Trainable {

    accept(Trainer trainer);

}
```

with an implementation like:

```
public Dog extends Animal implements Trainable {

  //... other dog stuff

  public accept(Trainer trainer) {
     trainer.train(this);
  }

}
```

And then keep the trainer the same way. All the animals will get dispatched appropriately.